# NSNotificationCenter not working ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm trying all kinds of examples of NSNotificationCenter, but none of them are working.  I have a UITableViewController that when a user clicks a cell, it opens a UIViewController that houses a WebView.  Just to get the ball rolling, I'm trying to have the UITableViewController log a message that it received the notification when the UIViewController with the WebView loads.  Here's what I have:

In MyTableViewController -

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
 if (self) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];
 }
 return self;
}


- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

 if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"]) {
    NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification!");
 }

}

- (void) dealloc
{

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Then in my UIViewController that has a webview in it, I have -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"TestNotification"
 object:self];

 ....
}
```

When I run and touch a cell in the UITableviewController to open the UIViewController with a WebView, no log message.  No crash, no nothing.  What gives?

Any help is much appreciated.

***EDIT***

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

 self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
 if (self)
 {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:)
                                                 name:@"TestNotification:"
                                               object:nil];
 }

return self;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.  Add a breakpoint to `receiveTestNotification` and see if it gets called.

Comment: it doesn't get called.  Used a breakpoint, and a basic log at start of method.

Comment: OK now try creating a single instance of the notification name and referencing that instead of the string literal.

Comment: If it helps, the UITableViewController is embedded in a UINavigationController which is one part of a TabBarController

Comment: What do you mean trojanfoe?  Sorry if that seems trivial, I'm only a couple days into ios and objc

Comment: In the `.m` of the class that *generates* the notification add: `NSString * const TestNotification = @"TestNotification";`.  In the header of the class that *generates* the notification add: `extern NSString * const TestNotification;`.  Then change all `@"TestNotification"` occurrences to `TestNotification` so you are certain that a single string name instance is being used.

Comment: trojanfoe... Your method worked...but so did the other guys comment, I had the strings different.  Overlooked a colon 100 times I guess

Comment: So now it is working... but, it's showing the log twice.. why is that?

Comment: like it's firing receiveTestNotification twice even though only one UIViewController that sends notification was opened

Comment: trojanfoe, can you make your answer an answer so I can accept it. I think I should accept yours, because changing to a constant fixed my string differences and thus the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Interface Builder then initWithStyle: wont be called as your initializer, instead override initWithCoder:

Comment: I'm using the storyboard

Comment: @A2345sooted that's going to do the same, override initWithCoder: instead

Comment: I'm lazier - I'd register for notifications in awakeFromNib. Or, even better, viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Abizern you can do that too, which will likely work in most cases, unless you decide an allocating one without IB later :P

Comment: I just moved the code that's in the initWithStyle of the UITableViewController into the - (void)awakeFromNib method,... but didn't work

Comment: @A2345sooted are you sure that the notification observer is setup before you're sending the notification? Put breakpoints in to verify the order, and make sure that both pieces of code are being run

Comment: @SomeGuy It's more a case of knowing (as you do) what initialiser is called when. I've know people who write a setup method, which they call from initWithCoder and initWithStyle.

Comment: @Abizern that's my preferred method too, making sure that it will work being created from both IB and code :)

Comment: Which alse works if you move setup to viewDidLoad - which is usually sufficient. All done in one place without duplication, and also further in the view Controller lifecycle, so things like segues or pushes are a teeny bit faster.

Comment: i moved it to initWIthCoder and still doesn't work... i edited my post to show how i put it in initWithCoder to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: In your initWithCoder: method you are adding an observer for "TestNotification:" but you are sending it out as "TestNotification", the strings need to be exactly the same

Comment: I suppose I had that wrong.. sheesh... before I made that change though, changing it to a constant like trojanfoe suggested worked also

Comment: it is working now, but it is showing the log twice... why is that?

Comment: check you some where call your postNotificationName